# Can't understand the behavior of deleting vars in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

Here is the issue:

```
var x = 5;
window.x === x // true. x, as it seems, is a property of window
delete x; // false
delete window.x; // false;
```

**BUT**

```
window.x = 5;
delete window.x; // true
```

**AND**

```
window.x = 5;
delete x; // true
```

What is the explanation for such behavior?

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: @Peter exactly what i was trying to explain, but in a much more accurate way. Please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially the reason is that declared variables are created with an internal `DontDelete` attribute, while properties created via assignment are not.

Here is great article explaining the inner details of `delete`: [Understanding delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

> When declared variables and functions become properties of a Variable
>   object — either Activation object (for Function code), or Global
>   object (for Global code), these properties are created with DontDelete
>   attribute. However, any explicit (or implicit) property assignment
>   creates property without DontDelete attribute. And this is essentialy
>   why we can delete some properties, but not others:

Answer (score 2):

You can use `delete` only for deleting objects, object properties or array element.

> delete ***expression***

`delete` will be not working if ***expression*** can't be represented
   as property. So `delete` can remove global variable, but not variables inited by `var`.

So, let me explain:

```
var x = 5;
```

You create variable in global scope by var, not property of window object. This var is just linked to window.x. And then you compare `window.x === x` it will return true. But:

```
delete x; // deleting variable, not property, return false
delete window.x; // resolve link to x and also deleting variable, not property, return false
```

**BUT**

```
window.x = 5;//add property
delete window.x; // can delete property, return true
```

**AND**

```
window.x = 5;//add property
delete x; //resolve x. it's a propery of window, return true
```

and older

In [ECMAScript 262/3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) as @Peter explain is available `DontDelete` flag. But in [ECMAScript 262/5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.1) in strict mode deleting is regulated by `Configurable` flag:

> When a delete operator occurs within strict mode code, a SyntaxError
>   exception is thrown if its UnaryExpression is a direct reference to a
>   variable, function argument, or function name. In addition, if a
>   delete operator occurs within strict mode code and the property to be
>   deleted has the attribute { [[Configurable]]: false }, a TypeError
>   exception is thrown.

Comment: Yes, but as long as I know any definition of global variable is a property of the `window` object

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understand that:

`var x = 5;` declared in the global scope creates the new `window` property `x`.

`window.x = 5;` declared *(whereever)* creates the new window property `x` as well. That's why `window.x === x` gives you `true`.

The difference is that javascript by default sets different descriptors for `x` property according to the way *(one of two above)* it is declared.

`var x = 5` is equal to:

```
Object.defineProperty(window,'x',{
  value: 5,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false
});
```

while `window.x = 5` is equal to:

```
Object.defineProperty(window,'x',{
  value: 5,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
```

The `configurable` descriptor, if `false`, forbides to `delete` the property.
We can assume, that javascript use `Object.defineProperty` with different descriptor settings under the hood when we declare variables in a simple way with `var` keyword or without it *(automatically assigned to `window`)*. 
You can simply check that:

```
var x = 5;
window.y = 5;

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,'x')); //configurable:false
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,'y')); //configurable:true
```