# Why hasOwnProperty returns true

Tags: javascript

This question is an extension of [Can't understand the behavior of deleting vars in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134578/cant-understand-the-behavior-of-deleting-vars-in-javascript/21135040?noredirect=1#comment31805763_21135040)

This is happening on Google Chrome:-
CASE 1:

```
var x = 5;
window.x === x // true. x, as it seems, is a property of window
window.hasOwnProperty('x');  // true
delete x; // false
delete window.x; // false;
```

CASE 2:

```
window.x = 5;
delete window.x; // true
```

CASE 3:

```
window.x = 5;
delete x; // true
```

If CASE 2 and 3 works(deletes x), then why don't CASE1 do the same ? I know delete only deletes any property and in CASE 1 x is a variable that should not be a property. But window.hasOwnProperty function returns true for it.

In firefox for CASE1: hasOwnProperty returns true and also deleting x returns true...

Comment: First case will be `true` only when `x` is declared as `x = 5;`, without `var`

Comment: Cannot reproduce using FF 26.0, FF returns `true` on all instances.

Comment: but when we declare it as var x, then also it is a property of window object..so it should delete

Comment: Yes I was checking in Chrome, in firefox the behaviour is different...

Comment: In chrome its ambiguity , that x is a property of window still we cannot delete it, when we use var x…. but firefox behaves in a consistent way..

Comment: Yes, it is, even down to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Let me to use my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21134644/2525067):

> You create variable in global scope by var, not property of window
>   object. This var is just linked to window.x. And then you compare
>   window.x === x it will return true.

Also `object.hasOwnProperty(x)` check what object has `x` as property (via `object.x`) not `x` from prototype chain.

Comment: Since this question is already answered by your original answer, it's a duplicate of the original question and should be flagged as such.

Comment: I totally agree you..I too think the samy way.. but I guess it is more browser dependent… like I just figured it out that.. firefox thinks in a different way..

Comment: @BhaskarMelkani How is it that you have the exact same comments as the previous question, but you didn't know about that question? Did you copy the code from somewhere?

Comment: May will be better to edit question and add link to original question? Because the main target of this question is why `hasOwnProperty` returns true.

Comment: sure sir…doing the same